# Is insertion order preserved in a Parse one-to-many relationship?

Tags: javascript, database, parse-platform

I need to know if the order in which one-to-many relational data is inserted in Parse objects is preserved when a query is performed. So if I run this:

```
var Post = Parse.Object.extend("Post");

var post2 = new Post();
post2.set("title", "Second Post");

var post1 = new Post();
post1.set("title", "First Post");

var user = Parse.User.current();
var relation = user.relation("likes");
relation.add(post1);
relation.add(post2);
user.save();
```

And then query a user's post in this way:

```
var user = Parse.User.current();
var relation = user.relation("likes");
relation.query().find().then(result => {
  for (const post of result) {
    console.log(post.get("title"));
  }
});
```

Will the above code always print?

```
First Post
Second Post
```

I have performed a few tests and it worked, but I need to know if this order is ensured by the parse server.

Answer (score 0):

The order is not ensured by Parse Server. If you want to retrieve in a specific order, you should use `ascending()` or `descending()`. For instance, if you want to retrieve in the same order they were created, you should do:

```
var user = Parse.User.current();
var relation = user.relation("likes");
var query = relation.query();
query.ascending("createdAt");
query.find().then(result => {
  for (const post of result) {
    console.log(post.get("title"));
  }
});
```

Comment: very good, but, I need to retrieve in insertion order even when the related objected are created in a different one, for example, in my example, if I revert the Post creations (creating post2 before post1) but still adding post1 before post2, then I still want post1 to be retrieved before post2. Would your solution still work?

Comment: To be very honest, I've never tested, but I think it works because of this: https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/cc6d474dcb49de39b55e681d319533686b544516/src/Controllers/DatabaseController.js#L950